# How can I create an alignment toward the top left corner?

Tags: html, css

To better understand, here's **an example**:

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g112qw6z/2/)

HTML:

```
<div id="a">AAAAAAA</div>
<div id="b">BBBBBBB</div>
<div id="c">CCCCCCC</div>
<div id="d">DDDDDDD</div>
```

CSS:

```
div { display:block; position:relative; float:left; }
#a { width:25%; height:100px; background-color:#ff00ff; }
#b { width:25%; height:100px; background-color:#ffff00;}
#c { width:25%; height:100px; background-color:#FF0000;}
#d { width:25%; height:400px; background-color:#CCCCCC;}
#e { width:150px; height:50px; background-color:#00FF00;}
```

The green box should fit just below the purple box.

---

**In the real world** I have a script that generates square box like this:

[real world](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFiy1.jpg)

The last two boxes, they would align themselves in the remaining space (the space is there, and perfectly calculated).

**The restrictions are:**

- *I can not change the order of the box*
- *The HTML has to remain as it is*
- *I can not add absolute positions (with top/right/bottom/left position)*

Is it possible ?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you use the CSS float property? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/float

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the heights of the boxes you can use `margin-top`.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/g112qw6z/3/

```
#d {
    width:50%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#00FF00;
    margin-top: -100px;
}
```

Or use `float`.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/g112qw6z/4/

```
#c {
    width:50%;
    height:200px;
    background-color:#FF0000;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a script that automatically calculates a grid of boxes starting from a dynamic scheme. Probably the only way is to calculate the displacement at the top with the "margin-top". Thanks! Stackoverflow is fantastic, fast answers!

Answer (score 0):

Add `float: right;` to your `#c` ID.

[jsFiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/g112qw6z/5/)

HTML:

```
<div id="a">AAAAAAA</div>
<div id="b">BBBBBBB</div>
<div id="c">CCCCCCC</div>
<div id="d">DDDDDDD</div>
```

CSS:

```
div { display:block; position:relative; float:left; }
#a { width:25%; height:100px; background-color:#ff00ff; }
#b { width:25%; height:100px; background-color:#ffff00;}
#c { width:50%; height:200px; background-color:#FF0000; float: right;}
#d { width:50%; height:100px; background-color:#00FF00;}
```